# Calculate center of mass with respect to radius

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I want to calculate the center of mass of a half circle with respect to the radius to avoid using x,y coordinates directly. Such that I can write $S_x=S_r\cdot \cos(S_{\phi})$

See here on Wolfram Alpha:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2%2Fpi)+integrate+r%5E2+dphi+dr,+phi%3D0..pi,+r%3D0..1

The result is obviously wrong. Is there a mistake in my formula or is it just not possible to calculate the center of mass with respect to radius/angle, whether in polar or spheric coordinates?

Comment: Alternatively you can find centre of mass of a ring element, and then integrate.

Comment: @samjoe How is that?

Answer (score 1):

This can be readily solved in the complex plane without reference to the Cartesian or even polar coordinates. We begin with the definition of the centroid

$$
A=\frac{1}{2}\int\Im\{z^*\dot z\}d\theta\\
Z_c=\frac{1}{3A}\int z\ \Im\{z^*\dot z\}d\theta
$$

We the consider a semicircle of unit radius

$$
z=e^{i\theta},\quad \theta\in[0,\pi]\\
\dot z=ie^{i\theta}\\
z^*\dot z=i\\
\Im\{z^*\dot z\}=1\\
\begin{align}
Z_c
&=\frac{1}{3A}\int e^{i\theta} ~d\theta,\quad A=\pi/2\\
&=\frac{2}{3\pi}\frac{e^{i\theta}}{i}\biggr|_0^{\pi} \\
&=\frac{4 i}{3\pi},\quad (\text{i.e., on the } y \text{-axis})
\end{align}
$$

as expected.

Comment: Sorry but what is $\{z^*\dot z\}$?

Comment: @samjoe $z^*\dot z$ if the product of $z$-conjugate and the derivative $\dot z=dz/d\theta$.

Comment: Very nice approach, took some time to figure out. Actually the idea is similar to Cartesian definition of centre of mass, right? Still the manipulation is nice!

Comment: Thanks. And, of course, the results is similar and, in fact, must be the same as the Cartesian approach. But I just love how much simpler certain things are when viewed in the complex plane.

Answer (score 0):

The centre of mass $\bar{\bf r}$ of an object $D$ is simply given by
$$
\bar{\bf r} = \frac{\int_{{\bf r} \in D} d {\bf r} {\bf r}}{\int_{{\bf r} \in D} d {\bf r} }
$$
In particular in 2D cartesian coordinates this gives for the $y$-component
$$
\bar{y} = \frac{\int dx \int d y ~y}{\int dx \int d y}
$$
which in the case of a half circle $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ and $y \geq 0$ results in:
$$
\bar{y} = \frac{\int_{-1}^1 dx \int_0^\sqrt{1-x^2} d y ~y}{\int_{-1}^1 dx \int_0^\sqrt{1-x^2} d y}
$$
If you want to do this in polar coordinates $(x,y) = (r \cos \phi,r \sin \phi)$, the transformation replaces $\int dx \int dy \rightarrow \int dr \int r d\phi$. So the last bit you need to do is reformulate the integrand, in this case $y$, also in polar coordinates, i.e., $y=r \sin \phi$ and you get
$$
\bar{y} = \frac{\int_{0}^1 dr \int_0^{\pi} r d \phi  ~ r \sin \phi}{\int_{0}^1 dr \int_0^{\pi} r d \phi}
$$
So what you missed in your integral is the $\sin \phi $ term. This means that rather than determining the average $y$-coordinate, you were measuring the average distance from the origin. Since that average distance $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} > y$ also depends on the $x$-coordinate you result is too large.

It is not really possible to use a similar approach to determine an average $\phi$ and $r$ value that would correspond to the centre of mass. The reason lies in the nature of the $r$ and $\phi$ coordinate system, where their directions depend on the location in the plane, which is not the case for cartesian coordinates. The only thing you can do is determine the integrals above in a coordinate representation of choice and after the centre of mass is obtained transform this to the relevant $(r,\phi)$ values.

In this particular case you could in principle obtain the average $\phi$ value which happens to correspond to the one for the actual centre of mass. This is accidental and only works here because there is a mirror symmetry of the object (the line $x=0$). In general however such calculation would be incorrect.

Comment: Actually what I want to do is to calculate the center of mass with respect to $r$ and $\phi$ independent of $x$ and $y$. Actually I wasn't measuring the weighed average from origin. This should give $\frac{4}{3 \pi}$.
How would I achieved this?

Comment: Unfortunately what you would like to do is not possible. I added a few comments with respect to your question to clarify the problem. I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You need a $sin(\phi)$ in the integration.

See: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2%2Fpi)+integrate+sin(phi)+r%5E2+dphi+dr,+phi%3D0..pi,+r%3D0..1

That gives $4\over3\pi$.

Comment: No, this is equal to integration over y. I don't want to do partial integration.

Comment: At least if it's avoidable, furthermore I'd like to understand where the mistake is with my integral.

Comment: You cannot avoid taking rectangular components!

Comment: @samjoe Rectangular components?

Comment: Rectangular components like $r \sin(\theta)$ and $r \cos(\theta)$.